# Finding diameter of a graph using linear algebra or BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-algebra, breadth-first-search

I got homework from school saying I need to find the diameter of a graph in CPP.
The problem is I need to do it for 5000 graphs with 1000 vertices each.
To save my graph I used vector of vectors like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph
```

I was able to find diameter of a graph using BFS on every vertex and returning the "longest shortest" path but it is really slow because of the terrible complexity

So I read online that I can use liner algebra to find out what is the diameter, but is it worth it?
Does it take the same time to compute at the end?

Plus does it mean I have to change from vector of vector to a matrix like this?

```
bool** graph
```

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Have you tried [Dijkstra Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) it finds shortest paths in `O(N^2)` time, meaning around 1 million operations for each of your graphs, it is not much for current CPUs/computers. And this is worst case time, in real case it will be faster.

Comment: @Arty But wouldn't that still mean finding the shortest path to all the 1K nodes, which would still translate to a 1K*1M = 1B operations?

Comment: @Zoso Yes, you're right. Then even better to use very-simple-to-implement algorithm of [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) which is `O(N^3)` but finds shortest paths for all pairs. Still it can be quite fast for real case. Not every real graph will use all 1B operations. But for modern CPUs 1B is also affordable.

Comment: Yeah, I too would like to know if the graph is undirected. We could apply the weighted quick-union FInd [algorithm](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf) and just iterate over the sizes of the final _trees_ of each node. The tree with the longest height would give the longest path possible or in this case, the diameter. I think that should bring it down to `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: I’m afraid your program have to be slow. Do you have a limit of time to do it? What it is the current time it takes to find the diameter for one graph?

Comment: Also interesting question is how do you compute diameter right now? What algorithm do you use for that? And what time it takes to compute one 1000-nodes graph?

Comment: I think what will matter to answer this question isn’t the worst complexity but the average complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest algorithm that I can come up with is well known [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm, which has complexity `O(N^3)` (N is number of vertices). It computes shortest paths lengths between all pairs of vertices.

For the case of your 1000-vertices graphs the time is quite affordable - around 1 billion steps, which will take several seconds for this algorithm per graph on modern CPUs, I hope you can afford this time. This algorithm will use 1 billion of very simple steps - 3 cache-reads + 1 add + 1 compare + 1 cache-assign.

Next C++ code does whole cycle - does input from string-stream, does initialization of weights, runs Floyd-Warshall algorithm to compute shortest distances between all pairs of vertices, finds maximal shortest distance, outputs results.

Multiple graphs can be easily computed simultaneously on different cores of CPU, which will speedup whole computation several times.

My algorithm supports any integer weights of edges, even negative weights. Input to algorithm should have weights matrix NxN size (N is number of vertices), zero weight denotes that there is no edge (i.e. infinite distance).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNj9owEL3nV0ypWCWCDR/bQ0sAqWq7Uk@VeulhQSiNHXBI7Cg2u2yr/e10bOcT6PZSc7Dnzdjz5s2EKM9vozTk29PpLeNReiAU5lKqgobZ0mmgRxopUbQRjGF820bCdCsKpnadi0xUjzmMK8hCxl0PfjuASyoym9l3gPFcwgK@91zj0muMvymMa/sd2ncte2wjWvZEI8b2esF5CstDJ7IuPPiIuTqzFzg2nP2iGwWR4FJhQIyMLOTeTjxYLmEawGgEX3nMOFPPTQqrz7xzNhfxDjF3PjOpQh5RlADpHM1V81R@UBdqpIxTy/Jpx1IKrnFuqdIOzXhoQrxKSVNPDK4GfeRGNmko1YYLtRGx24NVseIr1fNgsWjnmc14LqRXP6EX1q4YP5Tp9SJ@QXUxLvHN5sEAJl7jv9RYypZXGpUN3RZqhT6iwOMGrYqVWupjlxfxf4bR3vX8/CB3G3M@lg@@VGJ@EhmqSUHuRKEotpCUoksfPuJ0wk6pXM5GI8r9J7ZnOSUs9EWxHWlrdJ@KZ9L/Mu2/H/c/3P0IC7kL03RTz7VJE4sCGVr6zNDHbQ6VNgEMBqxh3o5ObHSiox/YunUh6ZaqO6kjHpK1btgYbm4wx5sFnMUZWao4Pa7BBcO9zbk/Y7i/zvDf9bxW098L6hI185Lh/0AJDa1vv8a5IrghVDYWW3qPwwyp4Nt2O/32x5qFR6JZDPWJ1aekGa3/07LX@2VYzKsq299ltUqeZURwza/JsaseTSTpeuqp/3ZQnf@QSBwUzOfQw@HOqKIF9LRpGSIMcSEyeKT4iRxrF7MuJWok0bt5kHKSBs6L45xOfwA)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string inps = R"(
        0 0 2 0
        4 0 3 0
        0 0 0 2
        0 1 0 0
    )";
    std::stringstream inp;
    inp.str(inps);

    size_t const inf = size_t(-1) >> 2; // Infinity
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> d; // Distance matrix
    // Input
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inp, line)) {
        if (line.find_last_not_of(" \r\n\t") == std::string::npos)
            continue;
        d.resize(d.size() + 1);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss.str(line);
        size_t x = 0;
        while (ss >> x)
            d.back().push_back(x);
    }
    // Compute shortest distances. Algo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < d[i].size(); ++j)
            if (d[i][j] == 0 && i != j)
                d[i][j] = inf;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < d.size(); ++k)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < d.size(); ++j)
                d[i][j] = std::min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]);
    // Find longest distance.
    size_t maxd = 0, maxi = 0, maxj = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < d.size(); ++j)
            if (maxd < d[i][j]) {
                maxd = d[i][j];
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
    // Output
    std::cout << "diameter " << maxd << " from vertex " << maxi << " to " << maxj << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
diameter 7 from vertex 2 to 0
```

As one can see it found diameter (longest shortest path length) equal to 7 from vertex 2 to vertex 0.

Comment: Actually this is the answer I was afraid of (complexity of N^3).
Thank you very much for your detailed answer and code, this is an amazing solution and I will use no doubt in here.